# SOQL CustomObject__Feed See Just see posted messages (different from draft) (Chatter)

Tags: soql, chatter, feeditem, chatter-feed, chatter-feed-tracking

I am doing the following SOQL query to retrieve all messages on Chatter for the Essai custom object

```
select CreatedById, CreatedDate, parent.Name, parentId, Id, Body, 
                                                  (select Id, CommentBody, CreatedDate from FeedComments where isDeleted=false And CreatedDate >: date.newInstance(2021, 09, 01) order by CreatedDate) 
                                                  from Essai__Feed 
                                                  where  
                                                  isDeleted=false And
                                                  CreatedDate >: date.newInstance(2021, 09, 01) And
                                                  (Type='AdvancedTextPost' Or Type='TextPost')
                                                  order by CreatedDate
```

The problem is that I also get the Draft messages for the Essai__c recordings

Previously I was using FeedItem with the Status field at Published but I would only like to retrieve for the Essai object

Am I obliged to go through FeedItem by putting the Ids of the records in ParentId? (SOQL limits on the number of rows returned will be reached faster) or do you know a solution with CustomObject__Feed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with SOQL query on `FeedItem`, but just set `Parent.Type = 'Essai__c'` in WHERE clause.

```
SELECT CreatedById, CreatedDate, Parent.Name, ParentId, Id, Body,
    (SELECT Id, CommentBody, CreatedDate 
     FROM FeedComments 
     WHERE IsDeleted = FALSE 
         AND CreatedDate > :Date.newInstance(2021, 09, 01) 
     ORDER BY CreatedDate) 
FROM FeedItem 
WHERE IsDeleted = FALSE 
    AND CreatedDate > :Date.newInstance(2021, 09, 01) 
    AND (Type = 'AdvancedTextPost' OR Type='TextPost')
    AND Parent.Type = 'Essai__c'
ORDER BY CreatedDate
```

But you'll need to run through query results to retrieve FeedItems with `Status = 'Published'`, because this field is not filterable.